# how to change the column (dataset)value names in repeater

Tags: asp.net, dataset, repeater

how to change the column (dataset)value names in repeater.

```
Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
Repeater1.DataBind();

<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BILLTYPE")%>
```

this my second column 'bill Type' now getting values 0, 1 like that.

if it is "0" i want to diplay as a "R.Cash"
and if it is "1" i want to diplay as a "R.Credit"

i'm trying using for loop, still didnt get.
please help me to change the column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your below line

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BILLTYPE")%>
```

with

```
<%# Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BILLTYPE")) == "0" ? "R.Cash" : "R.Credit" %>
```

For more values, you have to create below public method in your `.cs` file.

**Public Method:**

```
public string getBillType(string fsNumber)
{
    string lsBillType = string.Empty;
    switch (fsNumber)
    {
        case "0":
            lsBillType = "R.Cash";
            break;
        case "1":
            lsBillType = "R.Credit";
            break;
        case "2":
            lsBillType = "W.Credit";
            break;
        case "3":
            lsBillType = "S.Credit";
            break;
    }

    return lsBillType;
}
```

**DataBinder:**

```
<%# getBillType(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BILLTYPE"))) %>
```

Comment: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.BILLTYPE")=="0"?"R.Cash":"R.Credit"%>                                                                                              every column R.Credt is displaying, for "0" and "1" same value R.Credit is displaying.

Comment: Try this: <%# Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.BILLTYPE")) == "0" ? "R.Cash" : "R.Credit" %>

Comment: Thank you so much..<%# Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.BILLTYPE")) == "0" ? "R.Cash" : "R.Credit" %>  its working.     Can i add more than two values like "0"=R.Cash ,"1"=R.Credit,"2"=W.Credit,"3"=W.Credit,"4"=S.Credit,"5"=S.Credit ????

Comment: Yes. You have to create below method in your .cs file and write DataBinder like <%# getBillType(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.BILLTYPE"))) %> Method: public string getBillType(string fsNumber)
    {
        string lsBillType = string.Empty;
        switch (fsNumber)
        {
            case "0":
                lsBillType = "R.Cash";
                break;
            case "1":
                lsBillType = "R.Credit";
                break;
            case "2":
                lsBillType = "W.Credit";
                break;
        }   return lsBillType;
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DataItem.BILLTYPE")=="0"?"R.Cash":"R.Credit"%>
```

Comment: Your last edit has gone wrong. Can you fix it, please?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'R'.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/ternary-operator-in-gridview-datalist-and-repeater/